# Comparing Grouped Select Options using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have several select tags on a page and I am grouping them using the data attribute to make sure those with the same data key can be compared.  On submit, I want to check that the groups don't have the same option value selected.  So imagine it was a depth chart and you had football quarterbacks and running backs listed and you want to modify their position on the depth chart.  I can't have the two quarterbacks as #1 on the depth chart.  All I need to do is alert the user...."Hey you can't have the same value for this position" but I'm not sure how to do the comparison to get to that point using jQuery.

```html
Quarterback A
<select data-position="qb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Quarterback B
<select data-position="qb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Runningback A
<select data-position="rb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Runningback B
<select data-position="rb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Although it's not the same, can't you remove the taken position from related selects so is not available for selection (and add it back is becames available)?

Comment: That wouldn't work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used classes to identify your groups, instead of the jQuery data attribute.

```html
Quarterback A
<select class="qb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Quarterback B
<select class="qb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Runningback A
<select class="rb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

Runningback B
<select class="rb">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<button id="eval">evaluate</button>
```

​

Check this JS fiddle, i think it does what you want.  If you need help explaining the code let me know,

http://jsfiddle.net/SnJP4/5/

I have set up a routine to bind to the click event of the "evaluate" button. If you were to add more positions, like wide reciever, etc. then just add the name of the class the the `classes` array.  Here:

```
$('#eval').click(function() {
    var classes = ['qb','rb'];
    $(classes).each(function(index, el){
        var list = [];
        $('.'+classes[index]).each(function() {
            //alert($(this).val());
            list.push($(this).val());
        });
        list = list.sort();
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            if (list[i + 1] == list[i]) {
                alert('duplicate ' + classes[index]);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: You can give me a 1up too if you want :-)~

Comment: I don't have enough reputation it says. :-(